# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, moderation, closed-questions

My question

[How can I transition a conversation about Taylor ham, with a girl, into other topics](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/13012/how-can-i-transition-a-conversation-about-taylor-ham-with-a-girl-into-asking-h)

was closed as off-topic, and I don't agree with this.

The reasons given in the comments, as well as in chat, were that I can't ask for help on "what to say".

Comment: Pinging people in posts... doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 6):

Minus the commentary about foodstuffs, your situation appears to be:

> A girl gave me her number and I want to text her and ask her out.

Congrats! Go for it! *What do you need our help with?*

This is why I commented:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking what to say are off topic for this site.
>
> You already know what you want to do (ask her to dinner) and how to do it (texting), so it sounds like you're asking us to come up with the words for you.

In short, there is no indication in your question that this is a tricky situation and that you are having trouble with anything beyond "I don't know what to say, give me ideas".

A good question about talking to someone should explain *why* you are having trouble just saying the thing you want to say, and might include what you have tried in the past and why that isn't useful in your current situation. Try to identify the **skills** that you are having issues with, so that answers can focus on the approach you should take - not just words - and give advice that will be useful outside of just your narrow scenario. That is, explaining *why* a particular approach would work instead of simply prescribing a course of action.

As it was, your question didn't have any of that sort of information. In particular your note about

> I'm not exactly sure what to text her about.

sounded like you were looking for suggestions on future conversation topics.

(I haven't read the other question you linked, so no comment there.)

Answer (score 4):

> Why was my question closed?

Because, just like EmC commented: Questions asking on what to say are off-topic. Lemme quote the question:

> However, given that the only topic of discussion that we had was about Taylor ham, I'm not exactly sure what to text her about. I don't know anything else about her, other than the fact that she's from New Jersey. She was kinda cute, too, so I'm wondering whether she'd be interested in going on a date with me.

That reads a lot like you're asking us to write your text message for you, this was also explained to you. It was attracting a lot of answers that were doing exactly this as well, so it wasn't really meeting the [good subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) question guidelines posted by SE. Notice that out of 6 points mentioned there, 4 are directly about the kind of quality answers your question should inspire.

**Questions are put on hold so they can be improved and don't attract bad answers in the meantime, that then need to be changed later.** If you see a question that needs improving, you're encouraged to vote to close that one too. The community here isn't as active all the times, and sometimes stuff slips through the cracks. Most people seem to be afraid of closing a question hours or days after it was posted, but if that's what needed, it is what it is.

**Also note that I have not posted a question in awhile - in probably a month now.** I don't see why not posting in over a month gives this question more right of existence. Sorry.